# C# Is there a reason to avoid reassigning value in property setter?

Tags: c#

This is the pattern I see everywhere in "legacy" code, but now no one knows why it originated:

```
public virtual ICollection<SomeClass> SomeProperty
{
    get { return m_SomeProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (m_SomeProperty == value)
            return;
        m_SomeProperty = value;
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the benefit of the "if" check, if any? Can it be simplified to usual

```
public virtual ICollection<SomeClass> SomeProperty
{
    get { return m_SomeProperty; }
    set { m_SomeProperty = value; }
}
```

without any side effects?

Comment: Have you heard about `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Apart from an event on changes, no, this is meaningless afaik.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is the `m_SomeProperty` a private field? If so, this is meaningless. Much better to use auto-property instead: `public virtual ICollection<SomeClass> SomeProperty { get; set; }`

Comment: With sample you showed us - checking for equality make no sense. You need show more related code/examples which can provide more information about intents of original writer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't make much sense if the class doesn't implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

But if, you should only fire the [`PropertyChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) if a property was changed and not if the same value was assigned. The link contains an example.

Answer (score 0):

If the `m_SomeProperty` is a private field, this is meaningless. Much better to use auto-property instead:

```
public virtual ICollection<SomeClass> SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

*In this case, all occurrences of `m_SomeProperty` should be replaced with `SomeProperty`*.

Side effects are possible if the `m_SomeProperty` is a property itself. In this case it can have its own setter which should not be triggered if its new value is the same.

Comment: _In this case it can have its own setter which should not be triggered if its new value is the same_ - I think in this case setter of `m_SomeProperty` should handle this case